# Trimming seconds off a time value in SQL

Tags: sql

My current line reads:

```
SUBSTR(DIGITS(a.wotas),1,2)||':'||SUBSTR(DIGITS(a.wotas),3,2)||':'||'00' as TimeAssigned
```

Time currently comes back as 07:24:00. How do I remove the seconds value from this?

Comment: Which RDBMS product are you using ? Unfortunately date trimming functions are not a part of ANSII SQL Standard and each database provider invented their own solution (functions), for example `TRUNC` in Oracle, `date_trunc` in PostgreSql, `DATE` in MySql, etc. etc.

Comment: Does this help? https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/02/sql-server-function-to-round-up-time-to-nearest-minutes-interval/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the context or background of your question, but try this to remove the seconds part

SUBSTR(DIGITS(a.wotas),1,2)||':'||SUBSTR(DIGITS(a.wotas),3,2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTR(DIGITS(a.wotas),1,2)||':'||SUBSTR(DIGITS(a.wotas),3,2) as TimeAssigned
```

You really should do some reading on basic string manipulation. This is just putting together (stringing) different characters to format what you want. This really isn't "trimming off seconds of a time value".. in fact.. the "seconds" (:00) were just appended to the end by some other programmer likely. True TIME values (not strings) are manipulated in a much different manner.

Answer (score 0):

This will round up or down :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time DATETIME, @RoundToMin INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
RETURN ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,
@Time,121) AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) *  (1440/@RoundToMin),0)/(1440/@RoundToMin)
END
GO
```

And `SELECT dbo.roundtime(GETDATE(),1)` if you wish to round down subtract 30 seconds before you round.

Other examples

```
SELECT dbo.roundtime('17:29',30)
SELECT dbo.roundtime(GETDATE(),5)
SELECT dbo.roundtime('2012-11-02 07:27:07.000',15)
```

Or for a very simple solution that just removes this minute .

```
select dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,0,getdate()),0)
```

Credit https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/02/sql-server-function-to-round-up-time-to-nearest-minutes-interval/